# What is the easiest way to switch from a 64bit WAMPSERVER to 32bit?

Tags: wamp, 32bit-64bit, wampserver

I'm currently running a 64-bit version of WAMPSERVER (on Win7 Pro 64).
I've always been able to get anything I needed up and running except for SQLSRV, and have finally hit the point where I ***need*** sqlsrv, so I need to switch to a 32-bit wamp stack. :(

Since I'm a bit uncertain on the best plan-of-attack, I was planning to install a second wamp server (32bit) for testing, but that leaves me with two questions.

1. If I stop all my wamp services, and do a second installation of the
   32bit version, would that cause any problems (that'll end up being an even *bigger* time-sink) ?
2. Is there a better (already proven) way to migrate all the configs from a
   64bit to 32bit stack?

My whole reason for this plan is to test- migrate all my installed and 
enabled ext's to the 32 bit stack and see if they work (as well as 
my projects, of course).

Ultimately, I'd prefer to not have to go though the hassle, so if anyone magically came up with a solution to connecting to MS SQL Server from 64-bit PHP, ***please*** advise.
Other than that, would two installations of WAMP Server cause any glitches?
Or, is there already an easy/proven way to migrate from the 64bit to the 32bit vers?

Answer (score 1):

Read this question, i hope it will help you to reach to your solution
[Wampserver - mssql - 64 bit to 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654348/wampserver-mssql-64-bit-to-32-bit/20456603#20456603)