# Wampserver - mssql - 64 bit to 32 bit

Tags: php, sql-server, 32bit-64bit, wampserver, sqlsrv

I currently have a wampserver setup on a virtual server, its running apache 2.2.22, php 5.4.3, 64 bit.

I've decided its best for our system to connect to our large mssql database using PDO rather than odbc.

Our problem is that we have our 64 bit servers running 64 bit php. We've installed the sqlsrv (PDO) drivers, enabled the extensions etc etc, but it doesn't seem to be registering with PHP. Looking further into it, it seems the sqlsrv drivers are 32bit and incompatable with 64bit windows.

My question is,

- Is there a 64 bit version of the sqlsrv drivers for PDO?
- If there isn't, how easy would it be to convert our 64 bit wampserver to a 32bit wampserver?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't seen sqlsrv drivers crop up in 64-bit, but Google can tell you more than I can on the subject. "Converting" your 64-bit WAMP to 32-bit is just a matter of uninstalling one and installing the other. This is probably your best bet though, as there are other common extensions you won't be able to find in 64-bit.

Comment: @SarahKemp Thanks for the comment. I did previously do a search on google and went through too many pages! Unfortuantely it looks like I'll just have to remove x64 and replace with x86. Thanks again

Comment: @**Phil Cross** Thanks man for the posting this question, last night i started work with *MSSQL with PHP4.4*, so i am facing the same problem with 64bit OS & Wamp 64Bit, **Microsfot** :'( i google alot, but finally there was some suggestion, they said convert your 64bit wamp environment to 32bit, at some search i got this driver for PHP5.5 and 64bit enviroment, i tried it but failed, you also try this, if you get success in it, then kindly update me **Too :-)** Driver link
http://www.hmelihkara.com/files/php_sqlsrv_55.rar

Comment: @Qazi Unfortunately I couldn't get it to work, however I did use the ODBC driver rather than the SQL driver to connect to the SQL server which worked with some fiddling around! Hope this helps!